# Replace html hyperlinks with markdown links

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string like this:

```
'Hello, my name is <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/foo/bar">foobar</a>
My favorite food is <a href="https://google.com/food/pizza">pizza</a>'
```

I want to use javascript so all the html links to be replaced with markdown links like this:

```
'Hello, my name is [foobar](https://stackoverflow.com/foo/bar)
My favorite food is [pizza](https://google.com/food/pizza)'
```

How can I accomplish this? I know regex might be the answer but I'm not sure how to use it to solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, i don't think regex is the answer here. It's just a matter of reading some dom nodes and replacing them. not that big effort. Search for "how to get href value" and "how to get href text" to get started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by Lelio, using regex to parse HTML is not a good idea. You can create a dom node and get href and innerText and then replace it.

Below is a snippet.

### Steps

1. Create a dom node. Here, I used `p`.
2. Add the text as `innerHTML` of the node.
3. Use `querySelectorAll` to get all `a` tags in the node.
4. Iterate over the results and replace the `outerHTML` contents with `innerText` and `href` attribute of `a` tag.

```js
let text = `Hello, my name is <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/foo/bar">foobar</a>
My favorite food is <a href="https://google.com/food/pizza">pizza</a>`;
let p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerHTML = text;
let links = p.querySelectorAll('a');
links.forEach(x => {
    text = text.replace(x.outerHTML, "["+x.innerText+"]("+x.href+")");
});
console.log(text);
```

**Recommended reading**: [Why you should not use Regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2427065)

If there's a reason for you to stick with regex, here's a rough regex.   `/<a\shref=\"([^"]*)">([^<]*)<\/a>/igm`

```js
let text = `Hello, my name is <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/foo/bar">foobar</a>
My favorite food is <a href="https://google.com/food/pizza">pizza</a>`;
console.log(text.replace(/<a\shref=\"([^"]*)">([^<]*)<\/a>/igm,(match, url,text) => "["+text+"]("+url+")"))
```

**Note that this regex won't work if `a` tag have more attributes than href or if the `a` tag have html elements as children.**

Comment: @CubeyTheCube The regex part contains a snippet. It's hidden by default. There are lot of libraries available in npm which allows you to work with dom in nodejs